# Android animation XML issues

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to use Android's animation framework to have my ImageView move in a diamond pattern. Here's my animation.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="40%p" android:toXDelta="90%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="10%p" android:toYDelta="40%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="0"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="90%p" android:toXDelta="40%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="40%p" android:toYDelta="90%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="500"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="40%p" android:toXDelta="10%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="90%p" android:toYDelta="40%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1000"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="10%p" android:toXDelta="40%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="40%p" android:toYDelta="10%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1500"/>
</set>
```

My layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And my onStart:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.diamond);
    img.startAnimation(a);
}
```

When I start my application all I see is a blank screen for 2 seconds then my image pops into the upper-left corner of the screen. If I remove all but one of the translate animations I will see the image move in a diagonal line.

I would prefer to use XML to define the animation and not Java.

Does anyone have any insight into how I can see the entire animation?

-Dan

Comment: It appears it has something to do with using "%p". If I change "%p" to "%" then the entire animation works but is now confined to a much smaller part of the screen. According to the doc "%" is in relationship to the object and "%p" is in relation to the object's parent which is really what I want. Which explains why it is only doing the animation to a small box.

Comment: To further clarify, I would like to use XML to define my animation in relation to the parent of the ImageView I am animating. I will not accept any answer that says the framework is broken, nor will I accept an answer that requires the animation be defined in Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The animation attributes are relative to where they are when they start. This is probably a lot closer to what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="40%p" android:toXDelta="90%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="10%p" android:toYDelta="40%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="0"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-50%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="50%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="500"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-30%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-50%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1000"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="30%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-30%p" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Hi Reuben Scratton, i want to pause this animation on button click and resume on click again. is it possible?

Comment: Literally spent the whole day trying to figure this out.  I was about to give up.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.diamond);
findViewById(R.id.img).setAnimation(anim);
anim.start();
```

You should also probably change the animations to load one after the other. I think that set you have created will try to play all the animations at once, and that won't work very well.

Use an animationListener like this:

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.diamond2);
            findViewById(R.id.img).setAnimation(anim);
            anim.start();
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: This had no effect for me. According to the doc (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html), I should be able to specify a startOffset on an animation which should allow me to 'chain' the animation in the way I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one it works, i hve tested it

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="40%p" android:toXDelta="90%p" 
        android:fromYDelta="10%p" android:toYDelta="40%p" 
        android:duration="500" android:startOffset="0"
        />
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-40%p" 
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="40%p" 
        android:duration="500" android:startOffset="500"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-40%p" 
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-40%p" 
        android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1000"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="40%p" 
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-40%p" 
        android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1500"/>
    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this animation xml code. It works:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="40%" android:toXDelta="90%" 
    android:fromYDelta="10%" android:toYDelta="40%" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="0"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="90%" android:toXDelta="40%" 
    android:fromYDelta="40%" android:toYDelta="90%" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="500"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="40%" android:toXDelta="10%" 
    android:fromYDelta="90%" android:toYDelta="40%" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1000"/>
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="10%" android:toXDelta="40%" 
    android:fromYDelta="40%" android:toYDelta="10%" 
    android:duration="500" android:startOffset="1500"/>
</set>
```