# animation from xml android dynamic postion imageview

Tags: android, xml, animation

i want to add animation from xml to imageview. Before animation play i want to change XY location my imageview (dynamic position). I use method setX() dan setY() to move my imageview and set animation to my imageview with :

```
new AnimationUtils();
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
img.setAnimation(animation);
```

the problem is my imageview is not rotate with right pivot. Imageview still use coordinate 0,0 for pivot. How can i set pivot (50%) for new coordinate after i move my imageview?

i use pivot in my custom animation xml:

```
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android animation XML issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969689/android-animation-xml-issues)

Comment: thanks for your attention, but in my case i want to move my imageview dynamically and play rotate animation after set new position